# Pls advice how to start bitcoin trading

Tags: wallet

Please advice how to start bitcoin trading. Advice step by step Coze I am new Lerner

And which trading house is genuine and in case need refund our money can get immidatly back

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, any funds invested in cryptocurrency runs  the risk of being lost. That said, you’ll need a cryptowallet. I use Blockchain.info which holds bitcoin(BTC), bitcoin cash and etherium. There are other wonlibe wallets that hold more currencies so you’ll want to research and decide which is best for you but for bitcoin, Coinbase is fine. Also, there are are hardware wallets like the ledger nano which is probably the best option but costly. Coinbase is a trustworthy exchange to purchase bitcoin as well as Litecoin, ether and bitcoin cash. This can work as a wallet but not suggested. You can link your bank account or debit card both take time to be validated. Debit transactions are instant once valid. My bank transactions are now instant but that feature may take making some transactions. Once BTC is available on Coinbase you’ll need to send it to your wallet. Buying and sending currency all come with fees just so you’re a are. Once you get to sending BTC to wallet I can Answer any questions on that processs if need be but you might tigur it out on your own. Just make sure and information is entered correctly othewise you may lose your BTC.  Also remember to backup all account keys and passwords somewhere safe because asking to reset these are not an option. I hope that helps and good luck.

Comment: bitcoin(BCH) and bitcoin cash are the same. Also not etherium ethereum.

Comment: Yes, thank you I misspelled ethereum. Although I would disagree that BCH and BTC are the same as they have different value. I just put the wrong code after bitcoin, should have been BTC. But I understand BCH forked from bitcoin and are essentially the same

Comment: That's not the same. They are different.